# Database design by synthesis

Tags: database, database-design, database-administration

What is Database Design by synthesis. Is it simply the process of generating the minimal cover set from a set of functional dependancies or is there more to it than that? Its a topic thats really confusing me and help would be appreciated. If you can provide an example please do.

Comment: Did you google this and research it? What did you find?

Comment: I did but I'm unsure of the process involved. Is design by synthesis the same as Normalisation by synthesis and wich case Is the process simply to find the minimal cover set and then apply normalisation to 3rd NF and if all functional dependencies are maintained then apply BCNF?

Comment: This isn't really a code or programming question.  You might get a better answer on the Database Administrators group.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you'll have difficulty getting a good answer unless you read old papers or outdated textbooks on the subject.

In the 1980s, When relational theory was young and academically interesting, there was hope that database design could be automated through the use of a higher-level language to describe functional dependencies.  *Design by synthesis* is an idea in that vicinity.

The thing is that it's a kind of snake-eating-its-tail problem: the difficulty in database design ("normalization") lies in *discovering* the functional dependencies, not in representing them in an E/R diagram or SQL.  The problem is compounded by physical design considerations (performance, but also permissions) that would likely be inexpressible in such a language.

Any "normalization algorithm" presupposes as input something that never exists: a description of known functional dependencies.  If such a description did exist, it could verify they were consistent and it could minimize them.  But it doesn't, and anyone qualified to create one will naturally (almost unconsciously) verify and minimize them while expressing them in SQL.

Yes, *if* the FDs were completely and correctly described, the stumbling, iterative process of database design could be automated.  Also, if pigs had wings.

Contradictions and redundant dependencies tend to emerge during the design process *because* nothing can discover them *a priori*.  Any verification tool for them is thus subject to that oldest of computing truisms: garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: The potential value of synthesis is surely that it allows a correct database design to be derived from a description of a business domain in a formal grammar. For example Halpin's R-map procedure synthesizes a database design from a notation that subject-matter-experts (not just database designers) can understand and verify. I don't think that's an outdated notion even if it isn't widely practiced to its full potential. Good explanation though.